# GROUP BY ROLLUP Producing unnecessary rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT [Code],
       [Posting Date],
       [Document No_],
       [Description],
       [External Document No_],
       Sum(Amount)
FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY ROLLUP ([Global Dimension 1 Code],
                 [Posting Date],
                 [Document No_],
                 [Description],
                 [External Document No_]);
```

Whenever I run the query above, I want to subtotal Sum(Amount) per the "Code" column on the left using a GROUP BY ROLLUP, however it duplicates rows in a stair-like effect below. I feel like I am missing something obvious. The highlighted green row is the only row I want the ROLLUP to return. The 2nd picture is the desired result

[image]

[image]

Comment: `ROLLUP` "rolls up" at **every** level, not at each level. Those lines are effectively where the `GROUP BY` is just on `[Code]`.

Comment: So is there a way to only subtotal based on the `[Code]` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `ROLLUP` here. That will give you aggregations at every level of the hierarchy. You can use

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (([Code], [Posting Date], [Document No_], [Description], [External Document No_]),
                        (Code))
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.